# Change outer function variable with inner function variable? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript for a project and I need some help.

I'm trying to change the outer variables of `xPosition` and `yPosition` (the first 2 declared variables) with the new positions generated from the `getMousePosition()` to the `positionManager()` function but doesn't seem to work.

From what I have searched throughout the web (and on here), it may have to do with something with closures, scopes and local variables (in which i'm still confused a little by).

---

*Edit1:* Sorry, what I mean was that the `var xPosition = 0;` is not being replaced by the values in the `positionManager()` function. The intention was that `xPosition = mousePos.x` should replace it, but it doesn't seem to work.

*Edit2:* Everytime I move the mouse on the canvas, `getMousePosition` function generates the mouse coordinates. Then the `positionManager` takes those positions and updates (what I intend for it to do) the `var xPosition` at the top. However the `var xPosition` is still showing 0.

```
function mouseController(canvas, context) {

    var xPosition = 0; // To be replaced by values from positionManager.
    var yPosition = 0; // ^

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", positionManager);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", hideCoordinates);
    canvas.addEventListener("click", drawWidget);

    /**
     *Gets the mouse position.
     * @param canvas
     * @returns x and y coordinates. Use (VARIABLE NAME).x and (VARIABLE NAME).y
     */
    function getMousePosition(canvas, event) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

        return {
            x: Math.round((event.clientX-rect.left)/(rect.right-rect.left)*canvas.width),
            y: Math.round((event.clientY-rect.top)/(rect.bottom-rect.top)*canvas.height)
        };
    }

    /**
     * Manages and directs the mouse positions received from getMousePosition().
     * 
     * @param event 
     */
    function positionManager(event) {
        var mousePos = getMousePosition(canvas, event);
        // Formats a message that shows the coordinates.
        var mouseCoordinates = 'Coordinates: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;

        xPosition = mousePos.x; // Change the global variable to this new one.
        yPosition = mousePos.y;
        console.log("positionManager xPosition: " + xPosition); // Works fine, displays new coordinates everytime the mouse moves.

        // Sends the message to be displayed.
        displayCoordinates(mouseCoordinates);
    }
    console.log("global var xPosition: " + xPosition); // Still displays 0 even after positionManager
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *doesn't seem to work.*. Try to be specific. Maybe show what is happening versus what is supposed to be happening? Where are you checking the values an why are they wrong? Based on your code, the variables are both reachable within `positionManager` so it should work.

Comment: How do we execute this ? Seems good to me..

Answer (score 0):

You have added an *Event Listener* on "*mousemove*" event which invokes the `positionManager` method. Remember that this method is *only* executed if "*mousemove*" event occurs.

When the `mouseController` method gets invoked, the "*mousemove*" event doesn't occur before the method completes execution.

Which means that the control flow will jump to next line `canvas.addEventListener("mouseout",..)` and eventually the last line containing the `console.log(...)` statement without the `positionManager` function being invoked.

The execution is something like this:

```
var yPosition = 0;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", positionManager);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", hideCoordinates);
canvas.addEventListener("click", drawWidget);
// Then execution jumps to the last line as below.
console.log("global var xPosition: " + xPosition);
```

You may want to check the value of the variables `xPosition` and `yPosition` after the "*mousemove*" event occurs.

Comment: Even after every mouse movement, shouldn't the variables be updated with the one provided by the ones in positionManager and replace the initial ones? It's not doing that at the moment...

Comment: How are you tracking the new values provided in the `positionManager` by? Is it by the values in `"positionManager xPosition: "` line or by `"global var xPosition: "`?

Comment: The intent was to get the global var position to track it. getMousePosition calculates the position of the mouse on the canvas, then positionManager var mousePos allows me to use the positions. mousePos.x/mousePos.y display and hold the values. What I'm trying to do next is update the global values of "var xPosition = 0" with new ones by using "xPosition =  mousePos.x" to replace the global variable so I can use them for other functions. Hope you understand what I'm trying to say - I'm pretty bad at this stuff.

Comment: Once you encounter a "_mousemove_" event, you will get the updated values in your _other functions_ and you can check the same by doing a `console.log` inside those functions. Currently, the line [`"global var xPosition:"`] where you are expecting the values to be updated will execute only once. And most likely it will be executed before you invoke your _other functions_. Hence rendering you initial values.